# Android API's to record calls - direct from phone lines

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Does Android expose direct APIs to record two way calls?

I know there is a way to record audio source from microphone and speaker. Apart from this, is there any direct API's exposed by android platform to do the same?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html and use the audiorecord source Voice_Call

Comment: Thank you.I would be more interested if I can record voice call direct from phone lines.

Comment: Yes, there's [`AudioSource.VOICE_CALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_CALL). Just keep in mind that it isn't guaranteed to work on all devices.

Comment: Its work on both uplink and downlink voice call record but in some device's its not support. So you can use 'AudioSource.default' for all devices support

Comment: Does it record VoIP conversations as well?

Comment: In a VoIP scenario the VoIP app is typically doing a recording through the Android multimedia framework (it may be handled differently than a normal recording by the platform, but that's not visible to you). Most Android devices only allow one recording to be active at a time. There are exceptions, but you should not count on being able to record VoIP conversations.